# Have the Borg ever destroyed a species rather than assimilate them?

Tags: star-trek, borg

With their signature greeting;

> We are the Borg. Lower your shields and surrender your ships. We will
>   add your biological and technological distinctiveness to our own. Your
>   culture will adapt to service us. Resistance is futile.

they assimilate entire species and cultures. The Borg desire to assimilate entire species but for whatever reason have they ever literally destroyed any species?

Comment: Do you consider the complete assimilation of a species as being destroyed? Or only if the Borg go out of their way to not assimilate them and wipe them out?

Comment: I was thinking; Open up a can of whoop-ass, go medieval and engage with bad intentions wipe them out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are no known cases of the Borg wiping out a species without assimilating them.

Either a race contains unique mental, physical or technological attributes which makes them ripe for assimilation, or they have nothing of value to the Collective and are ignored (like the Kazon).

If a species was capable of resisting the Borg such that they presented a clear and present danger to the Collective as a whole, then the Borg would try to assimilate them to make that resistance quotient part of the Collective, rather than lose it. If the Borg were unable to assimilate such a species then they would probably be wiped out (see 8472 before Voyager intervened).

Comment: It seems likely that at least some of the "unworthy" species that originally occupied what is now Borg space were unable to survive, especially pre-warp civilizations.  The Kazon will probably face the same fate one day, unless the Borg are stopped.

Comment: @HarryJohnston There might be, but to my knowledge they've never been mentioned.

Comment: *If the Borg were unable to assimilate such a species then they would probably be wiped out (see 8472 before Voyager intervened).* Think interesting part of that would be the Borg's reaction to species 8472 and Voyager's knowledge. They clearly wanted to destroy them at that point.

Comment: @Mario Maybe. It is hard to say what the Borg would have done had they gotten the nanoprobe alterations. I think they would have adapted it to allow them to assimilate 8472 instead, since that was their original goal.

Comment: @Mario Not necessarily.  The first drone Voyager encountered was still trying to assimilate the 8472 ship

Answer (score 5):

#### Once a race has no further utility to the Borg Collective, the are absorbed effectively destroying that species. [Numerous species](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Borg_species) may have met their end this way.

- While the Borg do not boast of destroying species, we do know they are not above that sort of thing with their attempts to destroy the [Fluidic-space](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Fluidic_space) dwelling Species 8472.

> [The Borg-Species 8472 War](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Borg-Species_8472_War) decimated the Collective from 2373-2374. Voyager's liberation of Seven of Nine allowed Unimatrix Zero to create an active resistance movement in 2377.

- Species 8472's capacities to resist Borg nanoprobes with their aggressive biology and the destructive capacity of their organic ships made them a true threat to the Borg.

*Species 8472 Destruction of Borg Cubes*

- It is suspected the Borg may attempt to subtly coerce a species into developing new technologies through interactions on the fringes of their Empire. Once that species produces no new technologies, they are absorbed and their planetary infrastructures put to use by the Borg.

Comment: How rude. They didn't even let them finish their sentence.

Comment: Indeed. Species 8472 was not big on manners or introductions...

Comment: @Thaddeus You probably wouldn't be either if a race of cybernetic beings invaded your home and started aggressively proselytizing you.

Comment: I answer my door naked on the weekends when I hear the religious folk wandering the neighborhood annoying my neighbors. They only visit once...

Comment: @Thaddeus -Now that's funny. Do you give them a smile or a stern look?

Comment: I always smile.

Comment: Please, please don't link youtube videos in popular answers... it's been two and a half hours, and every time I finish one there's like 12 to pick from... i swear it's worse than tv tropes... have you heard of that place?

Comment: @corsiKa: What a subtly hidden revenge …

Comment: @Thaddeus I have to remember that one :-) The ones over here tend to bring a child with Down-syndrome and let that child do the initial talking. Turns my stomach every time. Me and some others in the neighborhood have tried to get Child Protection on to them, but they keep getting away with it. (When they are caught "in the act" the child is just along because they couldn't leave him/her at home alone.)